# IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Tags: python, keras, reshape, index-error

I am working on a python script using Keras, but I get an "IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1" on the last line below when I try to convert the label data to categorical format - I cannot see why there is an issue with the shape. Any help is welcome...:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Generate a random list of 10 characters 'a' or 'b'
data = ['a' if x == 0 else 'b' for x in np.random.randint(2, size=10)]

# Initialize a tokenizer to encode the characters as integers
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)

# Encode the input data as integers
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data)
X = np.array(X).reshape(1, 10, 1)
y = np.roll(X, -1)
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing num_classes=2 to num_classes=None fixed the issue.